# How to speed up pandas dataframe.apply() for large data

Tags: performance, pandas, dataframe, apply

```
def func(row):
if row.GT_x == row.GT_y or row.GT_x == row.GT_y[::-1]:
    return 2
elif len(set(row.GT_x) & set(row.GT_y)) != 0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0

%%timeit
merged_df['Decision'] = merged_df.apply(func, axis=1)

1 loop, best of 3: 30.2 s per loop
```

I'm going to apply "func" for all dataframe rows and the number of row is approximately 650,000.

I guess pandas.apply() takes more time than iterating by for loop.

I also tried lambda function rather than "func", but the result is same.

my dataframe has two columns named GT_x, GT_y
and, it has "AA" or "BB".
Function "func" detect GT_x and GT_y is same, it return 2, if one of them matches, return 1, else return 0.

And, I'm gonna make another column(Decision) by using apply function "func"

Could you recommend another faster method?

+

Here's sample data I have

```
GT_x    GT_y
```

0   AG  GA

1   AA  GA

2   AA  GG

3   GG  GG

...

65000 GG GG

index 0 result should be 2,
index 1 result should be 1,
index 2 result should be 0,
also index 3 and 65,000 result should be 2

Comment: Can you produce sample data?

Comment: row.GT_y[::-1] is a reverse order of row.GT_y....  So your second condition in your first if statement is ambiguous because you are comparing one value row.GT_x to the entire column of row.GT_y in reverse order.   Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @ScottBoston - Now I am going out, `merged_df = pd.DataFrame({'GT_x': ['AA1','BB','DD'], 'GT_y': ['AA','BB','CC']})` works for me for all outputs. But solution without `apply` for compare `uniqueness` of string I dont know. (maybe some list comprehension is necessary or maybe somethig else) Good luck!

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank Scott, I intended to apply the function for every row just one time. However, it looks it iterates more than I expected. Is it wrong usage of apply()?

Answer (score 1):

you can use df.apply(func, axis=1, raw=True) for faster computations
(in that case input of your function will be raw numpy array instead of series)

from apply function description:

```
raw : boolean, default False
If False, convert each row or column into a Series. If raw=True the 
passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just a 
applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better 
performance
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html